# Apache Ranger - difference between Read vs. Execute access (for Hive table)

Tags: hadoop, hive, file-permissions

Context - Hive tables with Apache Ranger to manage security.

Question - When setting the Read/Write/Execute permissions in Ranger, if a user has 'Read' access, can they run a select query?

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

When does a 'HiveQL' query need Execute access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help : There are different access criteria mentioned there :

> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization#SQLStandardBasedHiveAuthorization-PrivilegesRequiredforHiveOperations

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks!